# What is a magnetic field

Tags: magnetic-fields

What exactly is the magnetic field? I know what it does, but I want to know what it's made of at microscopic level, and how it gets its shape. By comparison with the electrostatic field, which is created by electric charges that attract/repel one another, what creates the magnetic field? The movement of electrons in atoms? Or, are there some elementary particles that create this field? If yes, which particles?

Comment: The electromagnetic field is the thing it is made out of. Really.

Comment: What about [Wikipedia's take on this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_field) does not satisfy you?

Comment: I'd rather ask people here instead of wiki because I can ask specific questions if I need to.

Comment: *"but I want to know what it's made of"* - suppose you were told that the magnetic field is made of X.  Would you not then ask, "well what exactly is X?   What is X made of?".

Comment: Yes, I would, but I don't know what "X" is.

Comment: Have you read the Wikipedia article on [vector fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_field)? Or on [Maxwell's equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell's_equations)?

Comment: @ACuriousMind  couldn't you understand that the user asks, and also specified in his comment, about the microscopic origin of the magnetic field. A feromagnet has a microscopic structure, doesn't it? A diamagnet has also a microscopic structure. The use asked what are the elementary (microscopic) bricks of a magnet.

Comment: @DragonSlayer3  In an attempt to propose your question for reopening, I reformulated it. But my formulation would be accepted only if you confirm that you agree with it. Here it is: *What exactly is the magnetic field? I know what it does, but I want to know what it's made of at microscopic level, and how it gets its shape. By comparison with the electrostatic field, which is created by electric charges that attract/repel one another, what creates the magnetic field? The movement of electrons in atoms? Or, are there some elementary particles that create this field? If yes, which particles?*

Comment: That covers everything I'd like to ask. Thanks, I'll use it.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Magnetic fields are caused by the electric fields. An magnetic field is an electric field that a particle in a certain reference frame that changed the effect. For example electrons moving in a wire produces a magnetic field as shown in [this video](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=video&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QtwIwAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D1TKSfAkWWN0&ei=VrT7VPDeLoGdgwTO8oNY&usg=AFQjCNHKWdkccIe_0hkaJEgCank8DtVVMw&sig2=y55IGKPYoYtX5quMHoI0AQ&bvm=bv.87611401,d.eXY). This video shows how magnetic fields are just electric fields in a different reference frame. Also, the electrons moving in an atom are magnets, but [this video](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=video&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCMQtwIwAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DhFAOXdXZ5TM&ei=VrT7VPDeLoGdgwTO8oNY&usg=AFQjCNGZ8nnqOEV9TuQ-tXCnQOsJAmB4rg&sig2=ZAW_6c7ztJJQNGx0bbLjig&bvm=bv.87611401,d.eXY) explains why only certain materials can be magnetized and why all magnetizable materials are not immediately magnets. This is due to magnetic domains.

Comment: There is nothing magical about electrons in this context: *any* moving charges work fine. And because "moving" is dependent on the choice of reference frame it is better not to try to form a strong distinction between electric and magnetic fields except in a introductory context: they are the time-like and space-like components of a Lorentz vector field.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me that it is a charge in general, I sometimes forget that since I usually associate magnetism with the electrons in the atom. As for the moving part of my explanation, since he is just learning what a magnetic field is, I thought it would be easier for him to grasp, but I will change it.

Comment: @StanShunpike , should I take the anwser down and wait for it to be closed?

Comment: Jimmy360, I have an understanding of Physics a little higher than high school I'd say, but I've been told that my comprehension level is outstanding for a 17 year old. So if you say something, chances are I'll understand it pretty well.

Comment: Do you know general relativity?

Comment: I've brushed it a bit.

Comment: How is knowledge of GR (or lack thereof) relevant?

Comment: The reason that moving charges create a magnetic field

Comment: That's the result of SR, not GR

Comment: oops, i must have messed up in the comment

Comment: I didn't mess up in the answer though